# How to display Generic HashMap entries

Tags: java, generics

I am trying to understand how Generics work and I have this piece of code to display the entries of newDetails a class with these kind of parameters Map. This is my code.

```
public class Map<Key,Value> {

    private Map<Key, Value> entry;

    public Map(){
        entry = new HashMap<Key,Value>();
    }

    public void putEntry(Key k, Value id){
        entry.put(k, id);
    }

    public void printMe(){
        System.out.println();
        for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> x: entry.entrySet()){
            System.out.print(x+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Chocolates Class

```
    public class Chocolates<T> {

    private List<T> listOfChocolate = new ArrayList<T>(); 

    public Chocolates(T choc){
        listOfChocolate.add(choc);
    }

    public void addChocolate(T getChoc){
        listOfChocolate.add(getChoc);
    }

    public List<T> getLists(){
        return listOfChocolate;
    }
}
```

Main method

```
public static void main(String[] arg){

        Map<Chocolates<String>, Integer> newDetails = new Map<Chocolates<String>, Integer>();
        Chocolates<String> choco = new Chocolates<String>();

        newDetails.putEntry((new Chocolates<String>("Cadbury")), 1);
        newDetails.putEntry((new Chocolates<String>("Hersheys")), 2);
        newDetails.printMe();
    }
```

Whenever I try to ran the program it just display this one

```
generics.Chocolates@9931f5=1 generics.Chocolates@19ee1ac=2
```

How do I display the actual entries like Cadbury 1 then Hersheys 2?

Also is there any way I can improve the main method or some parts of the program because I always create a new object whenever I add a new entry. Originally what I wanted to do is create a Generics version of this code:

```
Map<List<String>, Integer> newDetails = new HashMap<List<String>, Integer>();
```

As someone told me that its alot better to implement that line of code in a Generics Class. Any suggestions? Thanks

## EDIT 2

I edited Maps Class printMe Method as Nambari have requested

```
public void printMe(){
        System.out.println();
        for (Map.Entry<Key, Value> x: entry.entrySet()){
            System.out.print(x.getKey()+" "+x.getValue());
        }
    }
```

The output is:

generics.Chocolates@9931f5 1generics.Chocolates@19ee1ac 2

But if I add this line as suggested by Joao

```
public String toString(){
        return listOfChocolate.toString();
    }
```

output is :

```
[Hersheys] 2[Cadbury] 1
```

Thanks everyone for your help!

Comment: You'll be much better off *not* creating your own class named `Map`.

Comment: Yup thanks, originally the name is MapGenerics i just cut it out so it won't occupy space when I am editing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Override [`Object#toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in the `Chocolate` class:

```
public class Chocolates<T> {

  // ...

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return listOfChocolate.toString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Joao thanks for answering, how do I use toString method in the main program? I think that it will only convert lisOfChocolate list to String but the argument for the Generics Map Class is Maps<Chocolate,Integer> newDetails ... I don't think it would affect anything unless I wanted to display the contents of choco.getList method.

Comment: Hi, you don't need to explicitly call `toString`. Whenever you use `System.out.print(obj)`, internally, you are actually printing the result of calling `obj.toString` which, by default, prints the name of the class followed by the hashCode, which is what you are seeing, i.e., `generics.Chocolates@9931f5`. By overriding the `toString` method, instead of printing that funky string, you can define your own one. In my example, I'm printing the contents of the `listCfChocolate` list, but you can return whatever you like instead. Try it :-).

Comment: I see i'll try to find a way to incorporate toString then in the main method. Thanks for the tip ;)

Comment: @dimas: But again, you **don't** need to touch your `main` method. Just add the `toString` method to your `Chocolates` class.

Comment: Hi Joao I added your code in Chocolates class and it displayed correctly the entries. However I don't quite understand how it works because am not good with annotations, am just assuming that toString method was invoked during runtime by the compiler am I right on this?

Comment: @dimas: Whenever you want to print a `String` representation of an *object*, `System.out.print` (automatically) calls the object's `toString` method. By default, the class `Object` (from which every class inherits), provides a default implementation for `toString` which consists of the name of the class followed by its hashCode, which is what you were seeing initially, i.e., `generics.Chocolates@21345`. If you override the `toString`, as you did with my example, instead of calling the default Object's `toString` it will call the one you provide (which prints the collection).

Comment: @dimas: Here's a link that provides a (simpler) example of using toString http://www.javatpoint.com/understanding-toString()-method.

Comment: Hi Joao if I understand the article correctly and your explanation, whenever I try to invoke System.out.println it will convert the objects into String after I place that piece of code you gave me. Since I have this argument on main newDetails.putEntry((new Chocolates<String>("Cadbury"), 1)) so does that mean both the Key and Value are of type String when they're displayed?

Comment: Yes, what is displayed is a *string* representation of the objects, according to the object's `toString` implementation. You can try doing the following `String text = new Chococolate<String>("cadbury").toString()` with and without overriding `toString`, and try printing the value of `text` to see the differences.

Comment: Nice that means I still have tons of things to learn. Thanks for being patient with me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Update `printMe(..)` method `System.out`

```
System.out.print(x.getKey() + " " + x.getValue());
```

EDIT:

```
 public void printMe(){
        System.out.println();
        for (java.util.Map.Entry<Key, Value> x: entry.entrySet()){
            System.out.print(((Chocolates)x.getKey()).getLists().get(0) +" "+x.getValue());
        }
    }
```

NOTE: This code may throw `NPE` if `getLists()` is null

Comment: Thanks Nambari! I tried your suggestion however it still prints the same thing.

Comment: uhmmm actually the code didn't work lol its still displaying nonsense.

Comment: Hi nambari its working now, I tried to restart my editor and still using the same code you gave me I ran the program and its displaying this [Hersheys] 2[Cadbury] 1. Thanks for your help.